# Calling Android debug method from C++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to figure this out and I am at an absolute loss.

I am working with the JUCE library and have modified one of their sample projects.  My goal is to have a very simple Android app that is written in C++ and then ported to Android.  I need a function in C++ that I can call that will then call a function on the Android side that will return my heap size and other characteristics to my C++ code so that I can manage memory there.

If anyone has a simple solution that would be amazing.  Right now my current snag is this:

```
char const buf[] = "From JNI";

jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF(buf);

jclass clazz = env->FindClass("android/os/Debug");
```

But I keep getting an error saying that 'NewStringUTF' is not a _JNIEnv member... but if I right click on the method and jump to the definition, I see it in my jni.h file...  any suggestions? I'm working in Xcode by the way...

Comment: How do you get env? What's the datatype of env?

Answer (score 1):

Is it plain C, not C++? Perhaps your file has a .c extension.

If it's plain C it should be

```
 JNIEnv* env;

 JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &args);

 (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buf);
```